# SQL query to retrieve all employees in descending order of total bonus plus commission

Tags: sql, db2

,

I have a table EMPLOYEE with these fields:

```
    empno, firstnme, midinit, lastname, workdept, phoneno, hiredate, job, edlevel, sex, birthdate, salary, bonus, comm.
```

Do you know how to create an SQL query to retrieve all employees from the john.employee table in descending order of total bonus plus commission (BONUS and COMM attributes).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an olap question, this is a simple SQL statement.

```
SELECT   ...
FROM     employee
ORDER BY bonus+comm DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now is my OLAP question. If I would like to Modify my query to add a RANK column as the first column in the result table how can i do this?

Comment: SELECT RANK() over (ORDER BY bonus+comm desc), ... FROM employee

Comment: Thank you. What about if i want rows for the top ten (BONUS+COMM) values?